# How to use custom parameters in http triggered Azure Function?

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I have an Azure function using Functions v4 and .Net v7 and running isolated mode.

By default the signature of a function with anonymous access looks like this

```
[Function("MyHttpTriggeredFunction")]
public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
```

In asp.net I can create a controller action with parameters like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromHeader] string authorization, [FromBody] MyModel model)
```

If I want a Function that gets something from an http header and a custom model from the body, how can I do that?

Or do I have to get everything manually from HttpRequestData?

Comment: It’s all in the request. Have you not found samples that answer your question?

Comment: @Skin I know I can get the data like
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModelClass>(requestBody);
but I haven't found anything on if model classes can be used as input parameters in the method, like a controller action in asp.net.

Comment: I’m 99% sure you can’t do what you want but am more than happy to be proven wrong.